# Using SAML with JWT for Node API

Tags: node.js, api, jwt, saml-2.0, federated-identity

I'm building an Angular 2 application using SAML2 via the passport-wsfed-saml2 strategy https://github.com/auth0/passport-wsfed-saml2. When I receive a users info back from SAML I generate a JWT token which I use to authenticate a user on an API I am also writing.

So I have two servers, **APP/Auth Server** is serving my application as well as generating my JWT tokens and **API Server** has my API. Both servers have a copy of the JWT secret, so when a user sends a request from **APP/Auth Server** to the **API Server** I verify the token they sent with their request by verifying it with the secret.

Now for my questions, is it bad practice to have your app served from the same server you use to generate your JWT tokens? If so, what should I do here? Should I be doing more to authenticate a user on my API side?

Something about this just feels dirty....any help would be appreciated.

Comment: At what point did you add your jwt token to the saml authentication process?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having the application and authentication system in the same service is not a malpractice by itself. In general, decoupled services are recommended but this does not mean that the deployment can group services and of course depends on the context

If you are worried about sharing the secret key among servers, you can use an asymmetric key pair (private and public). The private key only needs to be known by the Auth Server in order to sign the JWT. The API Server can use the public key to verify tokens.

Comment: Thanks for the input, we've opted to keep the structure as is and use the asymmetric key pair you suggested. Thank you!